# Find the Laurent series about $z=i$

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

Let $g(z)=\cfrac{3z+1}{(z-i)^3}$. Find the Laurent expansion of $g$ about $z=i$.

My idea is first to find the Laurent series of $\cfrac{1}{z-i}$ about $z=i$, and then diferenciate, but I have problem with that. I
want to use
$$\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}z^n=\cfrac{1}{1-z},\quad \|z\|<1$$
How can I do that with $\cfrac{1}{z-i}$ about $z=i$?

Thank you,

Comment: The laurent series of $z\mapsto \dfrac 1{(z-i)^3}$ is exactly $\dfrac{1}{(z-i)^3}$.

Comment: It was simpler than i thought, thank you guys!!

Answer (score 2):

You have a direct way, upon writing
$$
g(z)=\cfrac{3z+1}{(z-i)^3}=\cfrac{3(z-i)+1+3i}{(z-i)^3}=\cfrac{3}{(z-i)^2}+\cfrac{1+3i}{(z-i)^3},
$$ this is the Laurent series expansion for $g(z)$ on $0<|z-i|$.

Answer (score 2):

Observe that
$$
\frac{3z+1}{(z-i)^3}=\frac{3(z-i)}{(z-i)^3}+\frac{3i+1}{(z-i)^3}=\frac{3}{(z-i)^2}+\frac{3i+1}{(z-i)^3}
$$
And this is the Laurent series for the function